# ng-class replacing my css settings automatic upon page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to learn a bit about AngularJS.
So I took a JSON and broke it into a table I  have created with Angular.
I wrote for the table a couple of CSS classes to make it a bit nicer.
When I run it I found something quite shocking, I can see in my browser that my table hes been change and was given automatically a class named : "ng-binding".

I cant really control my table style and it is vary strange !

Did any one else encountered that and can advise How can I change/cancel it , to do something so I can gain back the style control on the Angular objects ?

Thank you

```html
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $http.get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/chWykWNZcO?indent=2").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;   
   $scope.Fun = function(info){
   $scope.selected=info;
   console.log(info);
     $scope.show = $scope.myData[info].email;
  });
});
</script>
<style>

    body{
    margin:0;
   }
  
   .style1{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    align:center;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    height:5000px;
    
    }
    
   .style2{
    align:center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:252px;
    position:fixed;
    left:calc(50% - 126px);
    margin-top:0;
    }
    
   
    
   td{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    align:center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
      
   .container {
   padding-top:50px;
   width:252px;
   margin:0 auto;
   
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="style2">
  <table >
   <tr>
    <td>      
    </td>
    <td>
     one
    </td>
    <td>
     two
    </td>
    <td>
     three
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>  
 </div>
 <div class="container">
 <table class="style1">
  <tbody ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in myData" ng-click="Fun($index)">
   <td ng-bind="x.id"></td>
   <td ng-bind="x.name"></td>
   <td ng-bind="x.email"></td>
   <td ng-bind="x.city"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>click a row to get email adress:</legend>
 <div> {{show}}</div>
 </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As found in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

The `ngBind` attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

Typically, you don't use `ngBind` directly, but instead you use the double curly markup like `{{ expression }}` which is similar but less verbose.

It is preferable to use `ngBind` instead of `{{ expression }}` if a template is momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state before Angular compiles it. Since `ngBind` is an element attribute, it makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading.

An alternative solution to this problem would be using the [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive.

This means in your case something like this:

```
<td>{{x.id}}</td>
```

Instead of

```
<td ng-bind="x.id"></td>
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response.
Of  course before sharing  my question here I look a bit and try many things to change this status, one of them is what you suggested in your comment.

It does not change a anything.

Comment: sorry :) 
I am new to stack to so I thought he added your name peter.